# How can signed integers be converted to unsigned integers

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I am reading accelerated c++ and I just came across a line:

```
Vector.size() -100 yield unsigned results, which means that they, too, cannot be less than zero- even if vector.size() < 100.
```

What is happening here? Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: `std::vector::size()` returns an **un**signed integer.

Comment: Why don't you try it, and figure it out by yourself: `std::vector<int> s; s.resize(5); std::cout << s.size()-100 << std::endl;`.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Vector.size() -100
> ```
>
> What is happening here?

One of the operands to the arithmetic expression is signed, and the other operand is unsigned. Moreover, the rank of the unsigned type is likely higher than the rank of the signed operand.

In this case, the signed operand is converted to the unsigned type of higher rank. Since 100 is representable in the unsigned type, this does not affect the value.

The subtraction is performed on the unsigned operands. If the mathematical result of the unsigned operation would be outside of the representable range (i.e. negative), then the actual result would be the representable value that is congruent with the mathematical result modulo M, where M is the number of representable values in the unsigned type.

Since only positive values are in the representable range of unsigned integers, the actual result that is congruent with the mathematical result must also be positive.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I tried the program which the guy in comments mentioned. For some reason I am getting ```18446744073709551521```

Comment: @CeNiEi OK. Now you know that 18446744073709551521 is congruent with S - 100 mod M. Where S is the size of the vector, and M is the number of representable values in `std::vector::size_type`.

Comment: What does it means to be congruent with representable value modulo M. In unsigned type the max representable value is probably less than the value I got, then why am I getting such a big value

Comment: Oh so the congruent value is system defined and has nothing to do with basic arithmetic. Is that correct?

Comment: @CeNiEi The value that you got probably is within representable range. How else could you get that as a result, if that wasn't the case? For congruence, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_relation

Comment: @CeNiEi The range of representable values is system specific. It will probably be different between a 32 bit system and 64 bit system for example. But the result is otherwise reproducible across all systems with integer types of same size. Modular arithmetic is pure math, not system defined.

Comment: @CeNiEi Also see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic

Comment: I checked the the unsigned int on my machine. Turns out max value is 4294967295.

Comment: @CeNiEi Did you check the maximum of `std::vector::size_type`?

Comment: I checked the max value of size of  std::vector<int> . It is 2^30 - 1. Still less..

Comment: @CeNiEi how did you check it?

Comment: got a question on stack